# ERROR: could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.4": No such file or directory

Tags: postgis, installation

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, Postgresql 9.6. Previously I had working version of Postgis 2.3 but after upgrading to 2.4 when I query something from database with geometry objects I get `ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.4": No such file or directory`. If I make `count(*)` on the same table, it works well. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Executed `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.6-postgis-2.4`. Had to remove 
`ubuntugis-ppa-trusty.list` and `ubuntugis-ubuntugis-unstable-trusty.list` from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` before installing unmet dependencies:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>   postgresql-9.6-postgis-2.4 : Depends: libgdal1h (>= 1.9.0) but it is
>   not going to be installed Depends: libgeos-c1 (>= 3.4.2) but it is not
>   going to be installed Depends: liblwgeom-2.4-0 (>= 2.4.0~rc1) but it
>   is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have
>   held broken packages.

Comment: I recommend postgresql-10-postgis-2.4 with PostgreSQL v10 `sudo apt install -y postgresql-10-postgis-2.4 && sudo service postgresql restart`